# Is there enough datapoints to make a reasonable predcitction?

Tags: classification, dataset, predictive-modeling, random-forest, data

I am planning to use this dataset (for a school project) in order to determine the most important features in predicting whether a student will receive a placement.

Further I would like to create a model which would predict if a student will receive a placement based on their own features.

Link: https://www.kaggle.com/benroshan/factors-affecting-campus-placement

However, I have noticed that this dataset only has 215 rows. So my question is:

1. Is this enough data points for the tasks I plan to conduct?
2. If so, what classification algo would be most appropriate for a dataset which is this small?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Having enough data points is an empirical question. Split the data into train and test. See if the model trained on the training data can predict the test data.

For small data sets, pick algorithms that are less likely to overfit. One example is a decision stump.